# How is $S=\frac{A}{4G}$ not manifestly a solution to the black hole information paradox?

Tags: black-holes, entropy, event-horizon, information

If we take the black hole entropy $S=\frac{A}{4G}$ as given and let the black hole evaporate, the area of the black hole decreases, so the entropy of the black hole decreases. The entropy should tell us what is not known about the black hole. Thus if it decreases, something becomes known or in other words, the information must get out of the black hole in the form of Hawking radiation.

Moreover, we can reason that the information must be encoded near the event horizon of the black hole since Hawking radiation starts from there. This is very similar to Susskind's and Uglum's stretched horizon proposal or even AdS/CFT, but I don't think it's quite the same since we assume the whole bulk spacetime is manifest (e.g. AdS/CFT is either the bulk or the boundary description, not both). Here we don't assume any specific model of a black hole but just an abstract argument for the information getting out and where the information must be encoded at.

Clearly, people must have noticed this at some point, and the paradox still exists, so am I missing something?

Comment: All the area tells you is _how much_ information we've lost (if it is lost) into the black hole; it doesn't tell us _what_ information. If you asked me to recover data from a hard drive, I'd have to do better than say how much is there.

Comment: A more precise way to formulate the information loss paradox is that a semiclassical calculation done by Hawking shows that the *final state* of the system, after the black hole evaporates, is a *mixed, thermal state.* This is a problem, because time evolution under quantum mechanics is *unitary.* Unitary evolution can never allow a pure state to evolve into a mixed state. At a high level the problem is to explain either (a) exactly why the semiclassical calculation breaks down and what the right calculation is, or (b) explain why unitary evolution doesn't apply to black holes.

Comment: To some extent, the information loss paradox is similar to the ultraviolet catastrophe in computing the spectrum of blackbody radiation. We have a calculation where we follow all the rules of quantum field theory on curved spacetime that we think we know, but we derive a result that doesn't make sense. Most people believe that some new idea is needed (similar to Planck's hypothesis) that will lead to a new calculation with a more sensible result. But no one has been able to come up with an idea that completely resolves the issue, and also there's probably no way to experimentally test it.

Comment: J.G., so are you saying that we need to know the exact microstates of the black hole to solve the paradox? I don't think so because take the Page curve; the entropy (although it's entanglement entropy but we don't care, it's still entropy) need only to be the same at the starting and at the ending point for the information not to be lost. We don't need to know the exact microstates of the black hole.

Comment: Some authors like Wald and collaborators advocate that unitary evolution doesn't apply to black hole formation and evaporation because the resulting spacetime is not globally hyperbolic and one should not expect a well-posed initial value problem. That said, I don't agree with their argument 100% because it treats gravity semiclassically. I believe that as the black hole shrinks it will eventually become so small that quantum gravity is necessary. Moreover, in a fully quantum theory, where a black hole forms by scattering and evaporates, the ${\cal S}$-matrix should be unitary.

Comment: See also this very nice paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07143 by Andy Strominger on black hole information.

Comment: > *"the paradox still exists"* -- this seems to me to be a controversial statement. The "blackhole information paradox" seems to be a speculative topic, not everybody accepts there is a genuine problem with information, black holes and quantum theory. One has to assume lots of speculative ideas to arrive at that "paradox"; one can "resolve" it just by relaxing some of those assumptions.

Comment: @JánLalinský The only way to resolve it would be to actually show what the microstates are and how the black hole microstates evolve during an evaporation process, something that nobody have done so far in a realistic setting. It's fine to challenge an assumption (many solutions to the paradox take exactly this path), but the calculations need to be done. Otherwise you (not picking you specifically!) are simply not interested in the quantum structure of black holes.

Comment: @Rexcirus that's one possible view based on the assumption that everything including black holes has to be described in quantum theoretical way in a reversible way. If evolution is actually irreversible (as suggested by the necessity of using dirty QT rules such as the Born rule, or the Fermi golden rule, or the projection postulate), there is no paradox. Another model is that blackhole horizon is just a classical imaginary boundary that cannot be reached by any information carrying matter in finite time, so there is no information loss from the outside at any time.

Comment: As @JánLalinský said, there is a point of view that true horizon cannot form in finite time, so no information can reach it.